# Can I develop libraries (dll's) with Monodroid which are consumed by native Java apps?

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to develop a library (like a dll or jar) with Monodroid that can be called by Java applications on Android.

Is this possible?

If not, is there another possibility? (IPC...)

There is a solution for iOS, is there a similar solution for Android?
http://www.guidebee.biz/forum/viewthread.php?tid=172

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DLL compiled for Mono for Android will need the Mono runtime in order to run it, so it wouldn't be very useful for a standard Java app. Xamarin has some good documentation on the architecture available [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture). It is possible to go the other way around, though, and use Java libraries from within a Mono for Android application.